# Empty function of a listener and what's usage since it's a empty stub

Tags: android, listener

```
/**
 * Defines an interface for a callback that will handle
 * responses from the thread loader when an image is done
 * being loaded.
 */
public interface ImageLoadedListener {
    public void imageLoaded(Bitmap imageBitmap );
}
```

then somewhere in code

```
 // If in the cache, return that copy and be done
                if( Cache.containsKey(item.url.toString()) && Cache.get(item.url.toString()) != null) {
                    // Use a handler to get back onto the UI thread for the update
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if( item.listener != null ) {
                                // NB: There's a potential race condition here where the cache item could get
                                //     garbage collected between when we post the runnable and it's executed.
                                //     Ideally we would re-run the network load or something.
                                SoftReference<Bitmap> ref = Cache.get(item.url.toString());
                                if( ref != null ) {
                                    item.listener.imageLoaded(ref.get());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    final Bitmap bmp = readBitmapFromNetwork(item.url);
                    if( bmp != null ) {
                        Cache.put(item.url.toString(), new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bmp));

                        // Use a handler to get back onto the UI thread for the update
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                if( item.listener != null ) {
                                    item.listener.imageLoaded(bmp);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
```

My question is imageLoaded(Bitmap imageBitmap) is empty function it doesn't do anything except providing a callback.  So, item.listener.imageLoaded(ref.get()); what's significance of that?  or where does it lead to ? because imageLoaded is a empty stub function. Samething with  item.listener.imageLoaded(bmp); It seem to lead to nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageLoadedListener` is an interface. An implementation of this interface can supply its own implementation of `imageLoaded()` to do whatever it needs to do when the image has been loaded.